# Override micronaut loggers endpoint

Tags: logging, endpoint, micronaut

In micronaut we have the ability to enable [lots of endpoints](https://docs.micronaut.io/latest/guide/index.html#providedEndpoints). Here I'm using the [loggers endpoint](https://docs.micronaut.io/latest/guide/index.html#loggersEndpoint) defined in the application.yml file like this :

```
endpoints:
  loggers:
    enabled: true
```

This endpoint will be : http://my.host**/loggers**

Is there a way to change this endpoint adding a context in front of the /loggers ?

I'd like to have : http://my.host**/mycontext**/loggers

Or at least : http://my.host**/mycontext_**loggers

I tried to use the [@Replace annotation](https://docs.micronaut.io/latest/api/io/micronaut/context/annotation/Replaces.html) without success.

Any thoughts ?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not possible to set a context for only the loggers endpoint, however you can set a context for all endpoints with:

`endpoints.all.path: "/mycontext"`